# How to validate text box depending open input in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

i am building my website where i am providing option to user for build there `custom URL`. This custom url i am validating from my database that is `mysql`. if custom url is already present than they have to change there customurl.if user dont want custom url than they will not select that radio button.

what my problem is my code is validating that textbox even those they not choose option of customurl and because of this the form is not submitting.

here is my code:

```
    <html>
    <body>
     <form action="insertdata.php" id="contact-form1" class="mar_l10" method="post">
     <p><input type="radio" name="cust1" value="2" onclick="hide();" class="display_inline">Dont want</p>
     <p><input type="radio" name="cust2" value="3" onclick="show();" class="display_inline">Custom URL need</p>
     <p id="showlabel" style="display: none;" onblur="test(this);">Custom URL</p>
    <input type="text"  name="url" id="url" style="display: none;" onblur="test(this);" class="display_inline" maxlength="20"/>
<div id="user_status"></div>
     <input type="submit" id="continue_details" value="Continue" title="Continue" class="submit_btn" >   
     </form>



     <script type="text/javascript">
            function show()
            {
            document.getElementById('url').style.display = 'block'; 
            document.getElementById('hostname').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('checkurl').style.display = 'block'; 
            document.getElementById('showlabel').style.display = 'block';
            }
             function hide() 
             { 
             document.getElementById('url').style.display = 'none'; 
                 document.getElementById('hostname').style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById('checkurl').style.display = 'none'; 
             document.getElementById('showlabel').style.display = 'none';
             }



    var flag = true;
    $('#contact-form1').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#user_status').val() == " "){
     document.getElementById('contact-form1').submit();
        //return true;
    }
    else
    {
    test();
    $('.user_status').show();

    }




    })



    function test()
    {   
        var username = document.getElementById('url').value;
        var url = "check_url.php?username="+username;

       if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {

                var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                if(xmlhttp.responseText =='Custom URL is available')
                {
                    document.getElementById('user_status').innerHTML =result ;

                    document.getElementById('contact-form1').submit();

                }
                else
                {
                   document.getElementById('user_status').innerHTML =result ;
                }

            }
        }


        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);

        xmlhttp.send();

    }
     </script>



     </body>
     </html>
```

For custom url option click the database validation is also working correct and form also submitting. but if i choose dont need custom url option the form is validating url text box also.

please can any one help me on this.

thank you.

Comment: pls show your validations

Comment: thank you for your response.what validation you want to see..php code?

Comment: you told that `my code is validating that textbox even those they not choose option of customurl`, i want to see that validation

Answer (score 0):

You need to test to see if cust2 is checked when you do your test.

```
if($('input[name=cust2]').is(':checked'))
{
  test();
}
```

You should have your radio buttons have the same name to make them mutually exclusive. This is ancillary to your query, though.

Comment: for above code also it sumbitting when it should not. please help me on this

Comment: I think you lost a few lines of code above, I don't see anything that submits the form -- as the `e.preventDefault();` should stop the form from submitting.  There are a few suspicious blank lines where your other error might live (if you didn't space them over right or something here on StackOverflow).

Answer (score 0):

You must check the radio button before calling the test function, like so:

```
else if ($('form input[type=radio]:checked').val() == 3)
```

Comment: for this it sumbitting for any case.code i changed is var flag = true;
$('#contact-form1').submit(function(e){

 if($('#user_status').val() == " "){
     document.getElementById('contact-form1').submit();
        //return true;
    }
    else if ($('form input[type=radio]:checked').val() == 3) 
    {
    test();
    $('.user_status').show();

    }

 
 
})                                    for case of not sumbit it is sumbitting please help me on this

Comment: what is expected? when should it submit?

Comment: i need to form submit directly on click of option 1 and in click of option 2 it should submit only if customurl is available.